# Performance problems when adding columns to NSOutlineView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

In my application I would like to use an outline view to display attributes of different kinds of objects. Since the attributes are retrieved from an external database, they are not known at compile time; therefore, I need to add the columns dynamically.

I have set up Cocoa bindings to display the values, but I have run into some pretty serious performance issues. When I define the columns with bindings in Interface Builder, the performance is great. But when I add columns and bind to the same values programmatically, the application hangs for seconds when scrolling, using 100% of the CPU.

The data model is the following:
[image: Core Data Object Model Xcode]

Each dynamicAttributes attribute contains an NSDictionary with the following structure:
[image: dynamic attributes dictionary structure]

I use the following code to add the columns:

```
for (NSString *key in instDynAttsDict) {

    NSTableColumn *column = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:key];
    column.title = key;
    [self.instancesOutlineView addTableColumn:column];

    NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.dynamicAttributes.%@.value", key];
    [column bind:NSValueBinding toObject:self.instancesTreeController withKeyPath:keyPath options:nil];

}
```

I posted a test project here, with some sample data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5lGn_3atgSeNWVUX3l6cmVxUUE
You will need to copy the database `OSXCoreDataObjC.storedata` into the Application Support directory. (The specific path is logged out on app launch.)

Comment: You say the performance is great when you define the columns with bindings in Interface Builder. Did you add as many columns?

Comment: @Willeke I did not add all of the columns manually in IB, but the performance problems are apparent even if I add only a few columns programmatically. The application mostly hangs when scrolling horizontally.

Comment: There are too many observers. Each time an abserver is added, the observation info is replaced. Solution: don't bind the cells.